# Different appearance of the ng-show validation message

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure my ng-show validation message appear in different styles.

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.email.$dirty && form.email.$error.required }">
        <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="Text1" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.email" required />
        <span ng-show="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$error.email" class="help-block">E-Mail format incorrect</span>
        <span ng-show="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$error.required" class="help-block">E-Mail is required</span>
    </div>
```

And the different styles of the validation message:

#### not to be empty

[image]

#### to have the correct format

[image: to have the correct format]

Is it possible to have the same style for both cases?

Thank you very much for your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
'has-error': ... && form.email.$error.required
```

which only sets the `has-error` class if the form field is invalid due to the `required` validator, by

```
'has-error': ... && form.email.$invalid
```

which sets the `has-error` class if the form field is invalid, whatever the reason is.

Comment: I tried, but now I am receiving two messages "E-Mail format incorrect", "E-Mail is required" (both in gray color).

Comment: You replaced the wrong one. The one to replace if the first one, which sets the has-error css class. Do you understand the code you wrote?

Comment: I'm sorry - my mistake! I did changes on the wrong place. Now it works fine. Thank you very much!